# Android Studio: Cannot resolve method isShowing()

Tags: java, android

I am currently doing one of DialogFragments tutorials, but I've encountered something weird. Here is code:

```
package com.ja.testofallthing;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import static android.app.AlertDialog.*;

public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

public MyAlertDialogFragment(){

}

public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(String title){
    MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    Builder builder = new Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

        }
    } );
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
           if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
               dialog.dismiss();
       }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

This code is exactly the same as that one in tutorial, but I still get an error:

[image: error_message]

It looks like there is something wrong with import, but I have no idea what. I've already tried to change `import android.app.Dialog;` to `import android.support.app.v4.Dialog;`, because tutorial suggested to do so with other imports, but there is no such library. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is my android mainfest dependencies file, because there might be an error here:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ja.testofallthing"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: What version of the SDK are you listing as a dependency for your project? You probably need to add a later version.

Comment: DialogInterface does not have a method called isShowing() neither DialogFragment class, then the example you copied seems wrong

Comment: @LluisFelisart The class "Dialog" has a method isShowing() and it is extended by DialogInteface, so I think that it's okay. But here is from where I took this code: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-DialogFragment (scroll down to "Build a Dialog")

Comment: @jpaugh Added android mainfest dependecies file - for me it looks okay, but I am just a newbie :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `dialog` object to `android.app.Dialog` type like this and your code should work:

`((Dialog) dialog).isShowing()`

You should first check if `dialog` object is of type `Dialog`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. But I have one question: why I should check if `dialog` is of type `Dialog`? Is it just a good habit? Because it seems impossible that it might be of other type.

Answer (score 1):

`DialogInterface` is just a callback interface and provides just two methods: `cancel` & `dismiss`

In your case you don't have to check if dialog is still visible, this check is already implemented inside of `dismiss` method:

```
public class Dialog implements DialogInterface... {

    [...]

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == mHandler.getLooper()) {
            dismissDialog();
        } else {
            mHandler.post(mDismissAction); // calls dismissDialog from UI-Thread
        }
    }

    void dismissDialog() {
        if (mDecor == null || !mShowing) {
            return;
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: I really would like to mark your answer as the solution, but the topic is about not working method and the post above solves it. But thank you very much for it, it is really useful and simplifies the code and I'm planning to use it.

Comment: @BigRedChick Sure, but I don't recommend you to make a cast to a `Dialog`. It is not a really clean code.